# Android code crashes when opening in an emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am very new to java, but for some reason, trying to create an app
the app is building properly in android studio, but, when trying to open in an emulator, it is crashing.
[This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pMl_3Lf76sy82C0J4b-9ta4jbSHonJ2y) is my complete code

is the zip of the app, with I guess, the main error is

```
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);
```

**Logcat: Error**

```
2019-07-25 10:42:48.002 5383-5383/com.example.phocast E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.phocast, PID: 5383
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.phocast-j1KYRRVBUGO2ddQzmNBB8w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.phocast.ui.main.SunFragment.onCreateView(SunFragment.java:69)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
```

on line 69 of `SunFragment.java` code.

I don't understand what went wrong in the XML.

The corresponding XML is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

can someone please check?

**build.gradel**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.phocast"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.shredzone.commons:commons-suncalc:2.6'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: share crash logs

Comment: `Logcat: Error` is updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didnt-find-class-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709571/didnt-find-class-android-support-v7-widget-recyclerview)

Comment: how is your `build.gradle` like?

Comment: @shizhen: build.gradel added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

in `fragment_sun.xml` instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Because as in **build.gradle** dependency is `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0` but in `SunFragment` RecyclerView is imported from `androidx`

Comment: I have tried that, but without any improvement, as android studio is suggesting for androidx. One thing is, when I am trying to refractor, this says "No usage found".

Comment: Also, when I tried to change the card_item.xml to androidx, I got error`error: not well-formed (invalid token).
/home/rudra/Projects/Phocast/app/src/main/res/layout/card_item.xml: error: file failed to compile.`

Comment: @BaRud :When we use "Migrate to androidx"  then problem occurred in xml files. i have faced same issue. you need to do it manually for xml files

Comment: @BaRud: use `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` for card view.  when you type  view name like `<Card` editor will suggest you for both androidx import and support.v7. and make sure you are changing both open and close tags like `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>... </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`

Comment: Try to invalidate cache, restart, rebuild project and then use androidx.

Comment: This explanation is wrong. "but in `SunFragment` RecyclerView is imported from `androidx`".

Comment: @shizhen : i have checked `SunFragment ` class `RecyclerView ` is imported from `androidx` , if we change it to support library then code will work without changing in xml file

Comment: Note that the gradle dependency declares with androidx. the root cause is inside xml layout file. If you change to support library, then you have to change the dependency declaration as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx) support libraries so use `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Below screenshot is from your project search result:

[image]

Try to replace all those `android.support.v7` packages with the corresponding `androidx` package

See [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for detailed package mappings.

E.g. Change

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

to

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

This is **because** your source code is using **AndroidsX** package but your xml layout declare with **android support** package which is wrong.