# Can't import android.support.v7 and annotation libary with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

Im trying to go through this tutorial [Android Implementing Preferences Settings Screen](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/)

He imports `android.support.v7...` and `android.suppor.annotation libary...`

I did the most suggested answer and implemented these packages to my build.gradle and resynced it.

Android studio can't resolve v7 and annotations.

```
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.preferences"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

I expected, that after resyncing the libarys would be available and not the error message

```
cant resolve symbol v7 for instance.
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: I posted my whole gradle.build, hope it helps.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57195035/8034839 for similar issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **androidx**: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`.

In your code you have to import the [correct class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar):

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Also remove in your `build.gradle`

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

For the annotations [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/package-summary):

```
androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
```